# SVM Predict returns a large value that isnt 1 or -1

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm

So my goal here is to classify vehicles between sedans and SUVs. The training images I'm using are 29 150x200 images of sedans and SUVs, so my training_mat is a 29x30000 Mat and I use a double nested for loop to do this instead of .reshape because reshape wasn't working properly.

labels_mat is written so that a -1 corresponds to a sedan and a 1 corresponds to an SUV. I finally got svm->train to accept both Mats, and I expected that a new test_image fed into svm->predict would either yield a -1 or a 1. Unfortunately, svm->predict(test_image) returns an extremely high or low value like -8.38e08. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the majority of my code:

```
for (int file_count = 1; file_count < (num_train_images + 1); file_count++) 
{
    ss << name << file_count << type;       //'Vehicle_1.jpg' ... 'Vehicle_2.jpg' ... etc ...
    string filename = ss.str();
    ss.str("");

    Mat training_img = imread(filename, 0);     //Reads the training images from the folder

    int ii = 0;                                 //Scans each column
    for (int i = 0; i < training_img.rows; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < training_img.cols; j++)
        {
            training_mat.at<float>(file_count - 1, ii) = training_img.at<uchar>(i, j);  //Fills the training_mat with the read image
            ii++; 
        }
    }
}

imshow("Training Mat", training_mat);
waitKey(0);

//Labels are used as the supervised learning portion of the SVM. If it is a 1, its an SUV test image. -1 means a sedan. 
int labels[29] = { 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1 };

//Place the labels into into a 29 row by 1 column matrix. 
Mat labels_mat(num_train_images, 1, CV_32S);

cout << "Beginning Training..." << endl;

//Set SVM Parameters (not sure about these values)
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setC(.1);
svm->setKernel(SVM::POLY);
svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));
svm->setGamma(3);
svm->setDegree(3);

cout << "Parameters Set..." << endl;

svm->train(training_mat, ROW_SAMPLE, labels_mat);

cout << "End Training" << endl;

waitKey(0);

Mat test_image(1, image_area, CV_32FC1);        //Creates a 1 x 1200 matrix to house the test image. 

Mat SUV_image = imread("SUV_1.jpg", 0);         //Read the file folder

int jj = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < SUV_image.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SUV_image.cols; j++)
    {
        test_image.at<float>(0, jj) = SUV_image.at<uchar>(i, j);    
        jj++;
    }
}

//Should return a 1 if its an SUV, or a -1 if its a sedan

float result = svm->predict(test_image);

cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to fill your labels into the labels_mat. Simple mistake but it happens to everyone...

Mat labels_mat(num_train_images, 1, CV_32S, labels);

And that should work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

The output will not be -1 and 1. Machine learning methods, such as SVM, predict membership as the sign of the result. So a negative value means -1 and a positive value means 1.

Similarly, some other methods, such as logistic regression method use probability to predict membership where there are often 0 and 1. If probability <0.5, its membership is 0, otherwise 1.

BTW: your question is not a C++ question.